'Manage Service Principal' option in Azure DevOps not working
Clicking on 'Manage Service Principal' option in Azure DevOps literally does nothing. I am trying to trace the Service Principal (Azure Enterprise application and App registration) of my service connection in Azure DevOps which was setup by someone else, but clicking on it has no response. It has worked like 3-4 times in the past by redirecting to the corresponding Service Principal in my tenant.
Tried from different browsers made no difference. Does not work either for any of my colleagues. Clearing cache and history was of no use. I am sure its a not a permissions issue, as it works randomly, and a colleague who is the owner of DevOps organisation also has the same problem. The 'Manage service connection roles' option above it works always without any issues.


The link to Manage Service Principal will redirect us to the URL below.
https://portal.azure.com/{tenantId}/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Overview/appId/{spAppId}

I could reproduce the issue when I setup the ARM service connection with the service principal (app registration) generated in the Tenant (Micrsoft Entra/formerly known as AAD) which my user account was not invited in.
If your ARM service connection was created manually, you can get the tenantId and spAppId by clicking on the Edit button of this service connection.

Or you may call this API to collect the tenantId and spAppId information so as to generate the redirect URL. You may also proceed to check if you have access to that AAD.
Replace {endpointId} with the resourceId from the URL of your service connection.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=7.1-preview.4



Thanks for the solution Alvin. The problem was that I use different accounts for DevOps and Azure, and the DevOps account did not have Entra privileges. Providing it necessary permissions fixed my problem. Appreciate it.
